# Jquery Javascript Variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello i have searched the whole website for a soltution found something but didnt get it to work.

-I have the main function on the head area of the page. (This will return Data from a PHP)

-This Data i need as a variable but dont know how to handle.

```
function note(content,usern){
note = Function("");
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "note.php",
   data: {'token': content, 'user': usern },   success: function(data){ var myneededvar = data;  },    });  }
```

Ok thats works and also data is given out
Now im calling the function in the script like this

```
 note(token,notename);
```

and i need the result myneededvar

but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your variable `myneededvar` is local to the success handler function and will not be available outside.

Secondly, your AJAX call is asynchronous and you cannot expect to immediately get the AJAX return data in a variable right after the AJAX call statement.

i.e., you cannot do:

```
note(...); // call your method
alert(myneededvar); // this won't work as the AJAX call wouldn't have completed
```

Thirdly, not sure why you have that `note = Function("");` statement there. You should remove that.

Something like this should work:

```
var myneededvar;
function note(content, usern){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "note.php",
        data: {'token': content, 'user': usern },
        success: function(data){
            myneededvar = data;
            // use it here or call a method that uses myneededvar
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you kidding there must be a solution to work with the variable like in php anywhere on the site.

Comment: Not really, variables are function scoped in JS. You cannot `global` them like in PHP, of course unless they are globally declared in the first place (like in the answer).

Comment: See this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/